# Replace phone number in plain text with anchors in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

How can I manipulate a string to add anchors in place of phone numbers?

More in details..

I have as input a string like this:

`"Something went wrong. Please call us on 01 123 456 789 or 01 987 654 321."`

I want as output:

`"Something went wrong. Please call us on <a href="tel:01123456789">01 123 456 789</a> or <a href="tel:01987654321">01 987654321</a>."`

(note that there could be any amount of phone numbers and that the spaces between numbers in the actual content could be there or not)

How can I achieve that in Javascript?

Comment: apply regex with substitution then prepare the dynamic html and append it into DOM.

Comment: What's the regex please?

Comment: `(\b[0-9]+[ 0-9]+)` Something like this i guess

Comment: Regex is [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: @GaSacchi this is your regex `/(\d{2})[\s]?(\d{3})[\s]?(\d{3})[\s]?(\d{3})/g` . Please follow the link https://regex101.com/r/J8T0gk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do that with Regex.

```js
const input = "Something went wrong. Please call us on 01 123 456 789 or 01 987 654 321."
    
console.log(input.replace(/(\d\s*){5,}\d/g, x=>"<a href='tel:" + x.replace(/\s/g,"") + "'>" + x.trim() + "</a>"));
```

Comment: This seems to work well except for some spaces.
Output is `"Something went wrong. Please call us on<a href='tel:01123456789'>01 123 456 789</a>or<a href='tel:01987654321'>01 987 654 321</a>"`

Comment: I would go for `/(\d\s*){6,}/`, this ensures that there are at least 6 digits. `/[\d\s*]{6,}` would match an empty string with the length >=6 as well.

Comment: Solution: `.replace(/(\d\s*){6,}/g, x=>"<a href='tel:" + x.replace(/\s/g,"") + "'>" + x.trim() + "</a> ");`

Comment: @RolandStarke you're right. I changed that to `[\d\s*]{5,}\d` to avoid a matching whitespace after the last digit. The output should be correct now.